# Accessing innermost map in a map of maps of maps C++

Tags: c++, maps

```
using namespace std;
typedef map<string, map<string, map<string, int> > > MY_MAP3;
```

The above code is a snippet of a program I'm writing for a homework assignment. I basically want to to access the innermost map, and I need to do so with iterators.

The code below is what I am using to access the innermost map, but when I compile my program it throws a bunch "no viable conversion" errors.

```
MY_MAP3::iterator ptr = data2.find(sentence[0]);
map<string, map<string, int> >::iterator ptr2 = ptr->second;
map<string, int>::iterator ptr3 = ptr2->second;
```

How would I access the innermost map in this triply nested map? Thanks.

For further clarification, the line

```
data2.find(sentence[0])
```

is for returning an iterator for the outermost string. sentence is a vector and I'm searching for the frontmost word.

Comment: Try it with a simple `map<int, int>` first. Make sure you're 100% comfortable with map iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a simpler map:

```
std::map<std::string, int>
```

An iterator for this map will have a `first` of `std::string`, and a `second` of `int`. Can't be any simpler than that.

And all maps work exactly the same way. Therefore, when your map is a

```
map<string, map<string, map<string, int> > >
```

This means that the iterator for this map will refer to a `first` of a `string`, and a `second` of a `map<string, map<string, int> >`. Because that's what you have in your map.

```
map<string, map<string, int> >::iterator ptr2 = ptr->second;
```

No. As you should now understand, your `second` is a  `map<string, map<string, int> >`. It is not an iterator of any kind. This can only be:

```
map<string, map<string, int> > &map2 = ptr->second;
```

At this point if you want to continue drilling down into the second level map, you need to `find()` something first, in there.

Oh, and it also wouldn't hurt for you to check if your `find()` returned the `end()`ing iterator value, before attempting to do anything with it.

Comment: `MY_MAP3::iterator ptr = data2.find(sentence[0]);

map<string, map<string, int> > &map2 = ptr->second;  

map<string, int>::iterator ptr3 = map2.begin();`  

Would the above code work then? Apologies about the formatting, for some reason it won't let me put in linebreaks.

Comment: And what happens when you try to compile this?

Comment: The last line of code is supposed to get the beginning of the second component of the second level map. But for some reason I still get a lot of conversion type errors. "no member named 'second' in map2->second.begin();", "member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union"... I don't think my last line is set up correctly

Comment: You originally wrote `map2.begin()`, and not `map2->second.begin()`, as referenced by the error message.

Comment: Whoops typo on my part. I tried `map2->second.begin()` and it gave me those errors. I just tried `map2.begin();` and it gave me the error "No viable conversion from `map<string, int>::iterator ptr3 = map2.begin();`"